# Spring @GetMapping not showing anything on localhost:8080

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I started to learn Spring and I tried the @GetMapping function but on localhost:8080 I still get the error 404. The default port is 8080 on program settings.

This is my code:
package com.example.demo;

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }
}
```

I tried to look on the internet and imported another code and I have the same result. Any idea on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the path in GetMapping.

```
@GetMapping("/")
```

Refer - https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/

Comment: Thank you! I was watching a tutorial which is 2 years old and he didn't use the path, he just used @GetMapping and it worked for him.